# Can I use approxPolyDP to improve the people detection?

Tags: opencv, background-subtraction

Can I use `approxPolyDP` to improve the people detection?

I am trying to detect people using `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`. So after I  receive the foreground of the image I obtain all the contours of the image using this function:

```
Imgproc.findContours(contourImg, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

I iterate each element of **contours** variable and if the contour has a specified `contour area` => it's a person

My question is if I can detect the people shapes better ussing `approxPolyDP`.

Is it possible? If so can you tell me how?

I already used  `CLOSE` `morphological` operation before finding counturs

Comment: Why don't you try it? And see if you get better results?

Comment: I don't know how to implement it. I never used it. Can you help? Java code would be great.

Comment: Why do you suspect `approxPolyDP` will help you? In general the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) indicate that when using that method you will get a contour that fits better to the object (that is without many surrounding area). Therefore, you will be getting less area on your contours so you may have to edit your `>=` criteria

Comment: Ok. Thanks for clearing that out. I have one more question, maybe you can answer it here. It's about BackgroundSubtractorMOG2. Can you tell me how should I set the history value? I saw someone  doing:   mog2.apply(input, output, 1/history);

Comment: You should ask a new question or research on that, as it is a different subject and is not ok (and also not useful for users) to answer questions on comments. Anyways, if you want, I could write an answer for *this* question based on my comment and elaborate more if it helps you.

Comment: Ok answer for this question maybe in the future someone will need the help. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148346/discussion-between-rares-and-graycygnus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is if I can detect the people shapes *better* ussing `approxPolyDP`.

Although "better" is somewhat ambiguous, you could improve your classification by using that method. From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) we can see:

> The functions `approxPolyDP` approximate a curve or a polygon with another curve/polygon with less vertices so that the distance between them is less or equal to the specified precision.

That "precision" refers to the `epsilon` parameter, which stands for the "maximum distance between the original curve and its approximation" (also from the docs). It is basically an accuracy parameter obtained from the arc length (the lower the more precise the contour will be).

We can see from [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) that a way to achieve this is:

```
epsilon = 0.1*cv2.arcLength(contour,True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour,epsilon,True)
```

resulting in a better approximation for the contour. In the example in that tutorial they achieve an optimal contour using 1% of arc length, although you should carefully select this percentage for your specific situation.

By using these procedures you will surely obtain **higher precision** on your contour areas, which will better enable you to correctly classify people from other objects that have similar areas. You will also have to modify your classification criterion (the >= some_area) accordingly to correctly discriminate between people and non-people objects now that you have a more precise area.